# Toggle to switch "copy to output: always" for all .cshtml files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, powershell, fubumvc

I've got a fubu mvc application that only works on local iis if my view files (.cshtml) are copy to output and set as resources (via the properties menu).

However, for them to be picked up on windows azure they need to be set as "copy to output: always" but not set as resources.

Is it possible to change this setting in code or powershell? So I can flip a switch before pushing to azure, then flip it back after?

Comment: Why not leave the cshtml files as the default (Build Action: Content; Copy : Do not copy)?

Comment: When you say local IIS - are you using IIS or IISExpress locally? Or Cassini (the one built into VS)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but the answer to your question is that .cshtml-files must be set as **Build Action**: **Content** under Properties. This is the default build action for MVC-views.

**Copy to output directory** should be set to **Do not copy**